# Django 1.8. Can't show an image in form

Tags: python, django, forms, image

I'm using this package https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz to make a web quiz app. I need to add images to the multiplechoice answers.

So, I added to the Answers model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',
                           blank=True,
                           null=True,
                           verbose_name=_("Image"))
```

Images are uploading and saving into the DB.

The part that shows choosable answers are shown in template like this:

```
{% for answer in form.answers %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ answer }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I changed it to:

```
{% for answer in form.answers %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ answer }}
    <img src="{{ answer.image.url }}" alt="" />     
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it's doesn't work. It renders `<img src(unknown)>`

This is forms.py:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                               widget=RadioSelect)
```

And this is model:

```
def get_answers_list(self):
    return [(answer.id, answer.content) for answer in
            self.order_answers(Answer.objects.filter(question=self))]
```

Comment: Why would you think this would work? `answers` is a ChoiceField with tuples for values; nothing here has a `url` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, there are displayed choicefields, so how can I paste there an image?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I recently came across this problem, in case anyone out there is still stuck on it, here is how I solved it:

### Create a ImageField in the Answer model

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',
                           blank=True,
                           null=True,
                           verbose_name=_("Image"))
```

### Add a model method on MCQuestion

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...
def get_answers_images(self):
    return [(answer.id, mark_safe(f"<img src='{answer.image.url}'/>")) for answer in
            self.order_answers(Answer.objects.filter(question=self))]
```

### In forms.py

```
image_choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_images()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=image_choice_list,
                                                widget=RadioSelect)
```

#### PS: You might also want to change your QuizTake in views.py in other to not conflict with other types of questions, in my case I separated the forms for MCQuestion and TFQuestion

```
    # New
    elif self.question.__class__ is TF_Question:
        form_class = TF_QuestionForm
```

I hope this saves someone else from wasting hours on something relatively simple. While injecting the img tag directly might not be the "cleanest" approach I think it works well enough and doesn't require you to mess around much with the existing logic structure of the quiz app.

Answer (score -2):

to display image :-

add {% load static %} in template

sample snippet:-

{% block content %}

{% load static %}

#### Product List

```
{% if product %}

    {% for prd in product %}
            <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="{% static  prd.image1  %}">
    <img src="{% static  prd.image1  %} " alt="{{ prd.name }}" width="400" height="400">
            </a>
            <div class="desc"> <a href="{{ prd.productid }}/view"> {{ prd.name }}</a></div>
            </div> 
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     <p>There are no products entered by you .</p>
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

## in url.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    **from django.conf import settings**
    **from django.conf.urls.static import static**
    from . import views
    from .views import Productlistview,Productdetailview

app_name= 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^add/$', views.addproduct, name='addproduct'),
    url(r'^addsuccess/$', views.addsuccess, name='addsuccess'),
    url(r'^productview/$', Productlistview.as_view(), name='viewproduct'),
    url(r'^productview/(?P<productid>[0-9a-f-]+)/view/$',Productdetailview.as_view(), name='productdetailview'),
] **+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)**
```

## in settings.py -- project setings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
'/dev/projects/pro_mysql_practice/product/',
'dev/projects/pro_mysql_practice/index/',
 ]
```

Comment: The `static` tag has nothing to do with serving user-uploaded images.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but there are another images of another model on the page, and they all shown nice.

Comment: yw!! @satik-stack

Comment: @DanielRoseman i guess user uploaded images will be loaded to your local server path which you specified in the upload_to , from their, you can get your media/static urls to load the image in templates...